# Recursive call is not a tail call

Tags: kotlin, tail-recursion

When I present it with the following code (first line of function commented out because while it would be necessary for correctness, I want to make sure it's not what's causing the problem here), the Kotlin compiler tells me the recursive call is not a tail call.

```
class Env(val global: Map<Symbol, Term>, val outer: Env?, val local: Array<Term?>) {
  tailrec operator fun get(i: Int): Term {
    // if (i < local.size) return local[i]!!
    val o = outer!!
    return o[i - local.size]
  }
}
```

If I change the syntax of the last line to explicitly say `o.get(i - local.size)` instead of using operator overloading, it makes no difference. Ditto if I uncomment the first line.

I cannot for the life of me see how it fails to be a tail call. Maybe I've just been staring at it so long I'm overlooking the obvious. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**: If I rewrite it to take the object parameter explicitly instead of implicitly, the compiler is happy. Compiler bug?

```
tailrec fun get(env: Env, i: Int): Term {
  if (i < env.local.size) return env.local[i]!!
  val o = env.outer!!
  return get(env, i - env.local.size)
}
```

Comment: It's not calling itself recursively. It's calling the same function on another object.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Right, so it's calling itself recursively, supplying a different value for the `this` parameter. Presumably it would not object if it were a global function taking the object parameter explicitly instead of implicitly? So why object just because the object parameter is implicit?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but doesn't the function, when declared inside the class, have a third inherent parameter, the instance it is called on? As you go deeper in the call stack, all these receiver instances potentially need to be tracked. We can see in your specific case that it only needs to remember the top level receiver, but maybe the compiler isn't sophisticated enough for that.

Comment: Declaring the function outside the class as an extension function seems to resolve the issue. https://pl.kotl.in/Jk96Og_tR